# Can't add a link to a bookmark on another page

Tags: html

PageB opens but without anchor. *Please Help*

PageA:

```
<a href="folder/test.html#anchor" target="_blank">text</a>
```

PageB:

```
    <br><br><br><br>...
 <p id="anchor">Chapter 4</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The anchor on second page has to be more down for the browser to scroll, for example use div with height as the code below.

PageA.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PageA</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="pageb.html#anchor" target="_blank">text</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

PageB.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>PageB</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:900px;"></div>
        <p id="anchor">Chapter 4</p>
        <div style="height:900px;"></div>

    </body>
</html>
```